# seccomp and apparmor vs in-container root user

Tags: docker, containers, linux-capabilities, apparmor, seccomp

I'm trying to build Docker images without a privileged builder, therefore `DinD` is not an option.
I found now two ways of achieving that with either [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) or [img](https://github.com/genuinetools/img).

Both of them work in my local Docker setup and achieve that goal:

```sh
docker run --rm -it --cap-drop=all --cap-add=setuid --cap-add=setgid \
  --name img \
  --volume "$(pwd):/home/user/src:ro" \
  --workdir /home/user/src \
  --security-opt seccomp=unconfined \
  --security-opt apparmor=unconfined \
  r.j3ss.co/img:v0.5.11 build -t user/myimage .

docker run --rm -it --cap-add=chown --cap-add=fowner --cap-add=setgid --cap-add=setuid --cap-add=dac_override \
  --name kaniko \
  -v "$(pwd):/workspace:ro" \
  gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.7.0 \
  --dockerfile /workspace/Dockerfile \
  --context dir:///workspace/ \
  --no-push
```

The `img` image runs the builder process inside with a non-root user with `uid 1000` but requires `seccomp` and `apparmor` settings, whereas the `kaniko` container runs the builder process inside as `root user`, but doesn't need `seccomp` and `apparmor` changes.
I wonder now which is considered more secure, running a container where the process inside is run by the root user or running a container with a normal user but running with `seccomp=unconfined` and `apparmor=unconfined`.

Would be really great if someone could help me out with that and give me some clues.
My gut is telling me `kaniko` seems more secure because from what I understand, disabling the default `seccomp` and `apparmor` profiles has a bigger impact.

Thanks in advance.